# How do you make mootools drag and drop work with touch?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, mootools, touch, draggable

I have this Javascript Mootools code:
dragStart: function() {

```
var scatterGame = this; // get current object so that can be referenced once out of scope

        $$('.begin-word').makeDraggable({

            container: $('start-game'),

            droppables: $$('.begin-def, #start-game'),

            onEnter: function(draggable, droppable) {
                draggable.addClass('mouseover');
                if (droppable != $('start-game')) {
                    droppable.addClass('mouseover');
                }
            },

            onLeave: function(draggable, droppable) {
                draggable.removeClass('mouseover');     
                droppable.removeClass('mouseover');
            },

            onDrop: function(draggable, droppable) {
                draggable.removeClass('mouseover');
                if (droppable.hasClass('begin-def')) {
                    draggable.setStyle('color','green');
                    droppable.setStyle('color','green');
                    scatterGame.instructionStart();
                }
            }

        });

    },
```

It works great except that I need it to work with touch. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

The challenge to migrate this to touch, primarily, is that there is no mouseover in touch.

So, your first challenge then would be to consider converting mouseover events to touch events.

I see the mouseovers are perhaps, an unfortunately named css class and not necessarily an event, so those should not be a problem. Consider renaming that for maintenance. If there are any hover or mouseover styling/events associated with the draggable component, expect it to need to be migrated.

To add touch,

1. you will have to specify a touch framework, I see there is a [MooTools 1,3 demo here](http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-touch). There are others.

In the example:

> One big new addition to MooTools Core is the ability to detect mobile
>   events:  touchstart, touchmove, touchend, touchcancel...

1. Map the "ability to detect mobile events, to your existing: onEnter, onLeave, onDrop handlers.

Something like this:

```
//add touchstart event to the body
document.body.addEvent('touchstart',function(e) {
  //call onEnter, onLeave, onDrop

});
```

Also, take a look at the 'e' parameter that is passed in. You will probably want to query it to be sure it is a touch event that you want to pass to your draggable interface.

Hope that helps! Nash

Comment: The issue is I have no idea what to map touchmove to because onEnter is touchstart, but then it just moves...

Comment: Thanks for clarification, thinking... yes, this is probably a mousemove handler behind the scenes. I'll update post in a few...

Comment: Did you try onLeave()?  If that does not work you will need to either; 1. use a step debugger to find a mousemove handler that is internal to  'draggable', or 2. consult the documentation for how to expose the onMove method so that you can map it. Hope that helps! Nash